# Cómo generar un documento word (.doc) con estilos con Python

Tags: python, djangorestframework, ms-word

Estoy tratando de generar un documento de word con extensión .doc. Lo logro generar con la información necesaria, para ello hago esto:

```
logo = str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/cv_api/templates/logoutpl.png'
context = {'listaFinal': listaFinal, 'docente': docente, 'logo': logo}
html_string = render_to_string('home_page.html', context)
   
response = HttpResponse(html_string, content_type='application/msword')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="cv_personalizado.doc"'

return response
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que me sale el documento totalmente desordenado sin estilos. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para ponerle estilos? Cabe mencionar que tengo un archivo con los estilos llamado *estilos.css*, pero no sé cómo hacer para que se integre a la generación del documento.